# How to use methods like findOne() or find() to retrive documents from MongoDB in Node js when the models and schema are stored in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new to node and MongoDB and new to coding all together. I am working on a project where I create documents and store them in MongoDB. I am using Mongoose for all these stuff. Earlier I had all my `models` and `schemas` in the `app.js` file. And I was able to retrive data stored using my schemas in my webapp using `findOne()` or `find()` methods.

But recently, I have moved all my schemas and models to another file called model.js. And I have required all my models in my app.js file as well.

but When I try to retrive all my data in app.js using models and schemas defined, I am not being able to do it now?

Below are the codes to both of the file `app.js`:

```
// Load Models and Schemas
var Customer = require("./models/model.js");
var Purchase = require("./models/model.js");
var CustomerWeeklyFitnessData = require("./models/model.js");
var CustomerFitnessData = require("./models/model.js");
var Plan = require("./models/model.js");
var Trainer = require("./models/model.js");
var Session = require("./models/model.js");
var CompletedSession = require("./models/model.js");
```

and more code from `app.js`

```
// Post New Customer Data
app.post("/addCustomer", function (req, res) {
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const whatsappNumber = req.body.whatsappNumber;
  const gender = req.body.gender;
  const dob = moment(req.body.dateOfBirth).format("DD MMM YYYY");
  const trainer = req.body.trainerName;
  const plan = req.body.plan;
  const planStartDate = req.body.planStartDate;
  const registrationDate = moment().format("DD MMM YYYY");
  // Get registration date
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;

  console.log(gender);
  console.log(plan);

  const customer = new Customer({
    name: firstName + " " + lastName,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    whatsappNumber: whatsappNumber,
    gender: gender,
    dob: dob,
    registrationDate: registrationDate,
  });

  // Check for exisiting customer
  Customer.findOne(
    {
      $or: [{ email: req.body.email }, { phone: req.body.phone }],
    },
    function (err, foundCustomer) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (foundCustomer) {
          console.log("Customer Already exists!");
        } else {
          customer.save();
          // Send welcome email to customer
          const msg = {
            to: email,
            from: "hello@myfitsuburb.com",
            subject: "Test",
            text: "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js",
            html: "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>",
          };
          sgMail.send(msg).then(
            () => {},
            (error) => {
              console.error(error);

              if (error.response) {
                console.error(error.response.body);
              }
            }
          );

          // Send Welcome SMS to customer
          var mobileNo = phone;
          var message =
            firstName +
            ", Welcome onboard! We are glad to be a part of your fitness journey.";
          msg91.send(mobileNo, message, function (err, response) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(response);
          });
          res.redirect("/customers");
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Code in my model.js is

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// Mongoose schemas
// New Customer Schema
const customerSchema = {
  name: String,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  whatsappNumber: String,
  dob: String,
  gender: String,
  registrationDate: String,
};
const Customer = mongoose.model("Customer", customerSchema);
module.exports = Customer;

// Customer Purchase schema
const customerPurchaseSchema = {
  customerName: String,
  customerPhone: String,
  plan: String,
  planPrice: String,
  trainer: String,
  planStartDate: String,
  purchaseDate: String,
  purchaseTime: String,
  purchaseID: String,
  planExpiryDate: String,
  sessions: Number,
};

const Purchase = mongoose.model("Purchase", customerPurchaseSchema);
module.exports = Purchase;

// Customer Weekly Fitness Data schema
const customerWeeklyFitnessDataSchema = {
  name: String,
  phone: String,
  weight: String,
  height: String,
};

const CustomerWeeklyFitnessData = mongoose.model(
  "CustomerWeeklyFitnessData",
  customerWeeklyFitnessDataSchema
);
module.exports = CustomerWeeklyFitnessData;

// Customer Fitness Data Schema
const customerFitnessDataSchema = {
  name: String,
  phone: String,
  age: String,
  medicalCondition: String,
  allergies: String,
  weeklyFitnessData: [customerWeeklyFitnessDataSchema],
};

const CustomerFitnessData = mongoose.model(
  "CustomerFitnessData",
  customerFitnessDataSchema
);

module.exports = CustomerWeeklyFitnessData;

// New Plan Schema
const planSchema = {
  name: String,
  code: String,
  type: String,
  description: String,
  validity: String,
  sessions: Number,
};

const Plan = mongoose.model("Plan", planSchema);
module.exports = Plan;

// Trainer Schema
const trainerSchema = {
  name: String,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  whatsappNumber: String,
  joiningDate: String,
};
const Trainer = mongoose.model("Trainer", trainerSchema);
module.exports = Trainer;

// Completed Sessions schema
const sessionsSchema = {
  sessionDate: String,
  trainer: String,
  workouts: String,
  planPurchaseID: String,
};

const completedSessionsSchema = {
  customerName: String,
  customerPhone: String,
  trainer: String,
  plan: String,
  planPurchaseID: String,
  sessions: [sessionsSchema],
};

const Session = mongoose.model("Session", sessionsSchema);
const CompletedSession = mongoose.model(
  "CompletedSession",
  completedSessionsSchema
);

module.exports = Session;
module.exports = CompletedSession;
```

Now when I try to use methods like `findOne()` or `find()`, I am not being able to retrieve anything. How can I resolve this issue?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Hello, can you include what errors/issues you are facing? Any errors logged to the console?

Comment: I am not getting any detailed error. but when I try to `consol.log` any find or findOne, I get `null`

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing `module.exports` on every statement you assign it to another model.

```
module.exports = Session;
module.exports = CompletedSession; // Wrong!!, every module.exports you have assigned will be overwritten with the model CompletedSession
```

Also, you are importing the same thing to different models.

```
var Customer = require("./models/model.js"); // since your exported module is actually CompletedSession, Customer here will be the model CompletedSession
var Purchase = require("./models/model.js"); // here, you require the same module as above, and assign it to another variable, this will also be CompletedSession
```

**Solution**

When exporting, you should should separate the models with different properties on the module

```
module.exports.Session = Session;
module.exports.CompletedSession = CompletedSession;
```

When importing, you should specify the property of the module

```
var Session = require("./models/model.js").Session;
var CompletedSession = require("./models/model.js").CompletedSession;
```

**Alternatively**

You can use ES2015 *shorthand property names* to combine the export statements and ES2015 *object destructuring* to combine import statements to one single statement

```
module.exports = { Customer, Purchase, /* ... other models */}; // shorthand property names
```

```
var { Customer, Purchase, /* ... other models */ } = require("./models/model.js"); // object destructuring
```

[This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) has a good explanation and example about the basics node module import/export

Comment: Thanks! It worked. As I am new to coding and Javascript, It would be much helpful if you can drop some link to docs or reference material for this solution. I could understand it better reading the docs

Comment: official docs may contain too much information for starters, I have included a link to an article in the answer